# Vue2: v-model does not support dynamic input types

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When trying to create dynamic input elements i get an template compiling error like this:

> v-model does not support dynamic input types. Use v-if branches
>   instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/u8ncfdvn/

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <sr-el :persons="personsFoo" name="foo" type="number"></sr-el>
  <br>
  <sr-el :persons="personsBar" name="bar" type="text"></sr-el>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('sr-el', {
  template: `
    <span>
      <input :type="type" :name="name" :id="name" v-model="inputVal" :class="{invalid: !persons}">
      Here's the bound {{ name }} input value: {{ inputVal }}
    </span>
  `,
  props: ['type', 'name', 'persons'],
  data() {
    return {
      inputVal: this.persons,
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      personsFoo: 1,
      personsBar: 2,
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

As of [version 2.5.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.5.0), Vue supports dynamic input types, so you're now able to bind `type` to a data property like you want:

```
<input :type="type" :name="name" :id="name" v-model="inputVal">
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/u8ncfdvn/1/)

---

For anyone who still needs to use a version earlier than 2.5:

What this error is saying is that, if you dynamically change the input type being sent to the component, Vue will not update the input element to change its type.

You should use `v-if` statements instead:

```
<input v-if="type == 'text'" type="text" :name="name" :id="name" v-model="inputVal">
<input v-if="type == 'number'" type="number" :name="name" :id="name" v-model="inputVal">
```

Comment: hmm, not really sexy

Comment: No it's not. The bigger question: why do you want a component that basically just mimics the functionality of an `input` tag?

Comment: i want to be able to manage existence, validation and configuration of different form elements.

Comment: Since all of that will probably be different based on the type of input, I'd make separate components for each type (`sr-text-el`, `sr-number-el`, etc), instead of making one component to do it all

Comment: hmmm, ok. will do some more research.

Comment: @Mike you're able to do this now in v2.5 see my edit