# dynamic change types,lable Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to be able to dynamically change the types,lables of an input field between text and email,number.
how that possible ,i am new in vue js:

```
<input type="email">
```

Comment: Can you please explain the context? Why would you like to do this? What is the logic behind?

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461188/vue2-v-model-does-not-support-dynamic-input-types

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare this in your data:

```
data () {
  return {
    inputType: "text",
    lableName: "Default",
  }
}
```

Now you use these variables in your html:

```
<label>{{ lableName }}</label>
<input :type="inputType">
```

The last part is to define the logic when these values change. However, I don't know when or why you want to change this. If you elaborate I can edit.

Hope this helps already :)

Comment: so i have  an array in data function so i want to have for each index in array input with index name                                                                                                                                  data () {
    return {
      data: {
        headers: [
          'Email',
          'Name',
          'DESC',
          'Notes',
          'reason'
        ] as yous see top this my data when i have a lable it should change                              like <lable> Email</label> ,<lable> Name</label>,<lable> DESC</label>                @Wimancesir

Answer (score 1):

You can use below syntax to make it dynamic
For html:

```
<input :type="inputType">
```

In data:

```
data () {
  return {
    inputType: 'text'
  };
}
```